# How to resolve merge conflict using 'theirs' then 'mine' for a specific file during Git pull/checkout

Tags: git, git-merge

I work on a file (dbscript.txt) which is used by multiple developers frequently and thus it goes to conflicting status very fast. So, to push the changes I pull, resolve conflict and then push it again.

Is there any way with which we can pull/checkout this specific file so that it resolve merge conflict using 'theirs' then append 'mine' for this specific file?

Tried using below mentioned command which checkout using 'theirs', but it wipes out 'mine'.
Searching for a command which pull/checkout using 'theirs' but also append 'mine' so don't need to merge conflicts externally.

```
git checkout --theirs dbscript.txt
```

Comment: You may need a custom merge drive, https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes#_defining_a_custom_merge_driver.

Comment: See also "union merge", but remember that union merge doesn't respect ordering constraints and may not be suitable for your case. In all cases you'll need a custom driver. Merge drivers are great but they are *hard to write*, which is why people don't. :-)

Comment: Thanks @ElpieKay I read the reference you mentioned and will sure try to write custom merge driver.

Comment: Felt same as @torek mentioned, writing custom merge driver is difficult. :-(